# Find hole in schedule

Tags: c#, schedule

I’m looking for a way to find holes in a schedule, times that does not have a booking.

I have a simple class in C# that looks like:

```
DateTime StartTime { get; set; }

Datetime EndTime { get; set; }

public int User_ID { get; set; }
```

The same class is used for the bookings aswell.
Let’s assume I have these objects:

```
Schedule: StartTime "2017-03-14 08:00" - EndTime "2017-03-14 16:00" (8 hours)
Booking: StartTime "2017-03-14 09:00" - Endtime "2017-03-14 10:00" (1 hour)
```

My final result from this would be 2 objects that represents the “free time”:

```
Free: StartTime "2017-03-14 08:00" EndTime: "2017-03-14 09:00" (1 hour)
Free: StartTime "2017-03-14 10:00" EndTime: "2017-03-14 16:00"(6 hour)
```

How would I check this in C#?

I'm thinking about looping the Schedule and split  them on start/end of each booking, but I'm not sure how to do it.

Comment: So it means that you can have two or more booked slots (IE 12-13 and 14-15) resulting in 4 free slots? (08-09, 10-12, 13-14 and 15-16)

Comment: Can there be overlapping bookings? Are the instances of the this class are ordered?

Comment: @Steve Yes, correct. That would return in 4 free slots.

Comment: *I'm thinking about looping the Schedule and split them on start/end of each booking, but I'm not sure how to do it.* Correct... It will be a pain probably.

Comment: @OriNachum Yes, unfortunately there can be "double bookings", meaning they overlap. Both where it begins and ends before, and after start/end times. I guess I can sort them in whatever way I want them

Comment: Do you care about complexity? Basically, you can double-loop once and merge bookings. This will leave you with exclusive bookings only. Now you can sort them out, and create the relevant 'free-bookings'  :)

Comment: I'd have a look at the [Time Period Library](https://www.codeproject.com/articles/168662/time-period-library-for-net), I believe it has methods that could help you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is easier than I thought... Note that this code isn't optimized, and this algorithm isn't probably very optimizable:

```
public class TimeSegment
{
    public readonly DateTime StartTime;

    public readonly DateTime EndTime;

    public TimeSegment(DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime)
    {
        StartTime = startTime;
        EndTime = endTime;
    }

    public TimeSegment[] Subtract(TimeSegment other)
    {
        // 8-10 Subtract 10-11 = 8-10
        if (StartTime > other.EndTime || other.StartTime > EndTime)
        {
            // If there is no intersection, we return { this }
            // (no subtraction)
            return new[] { this };
        }

        if (StartTime >= other.StartTime)
        {
            // 8-10 Subtract 8-10 = (nothing)
            // 8-10 Subtract 7-11 = (nothing)
            if (EndTime <= other.EndTime)
            {
                // Total subtraction, nothing remains!
                return new TimeSegment[0];
            }
            else
            {
                // 8-10 Subtract 7-9 = 9-10
                return new[] { new TimeSegment(other.EndTime, EndTime) };
            }
        }

        // 8-12 Subtract 9-13 = 8-9
        if (EndTime <= other.EndTime)
        {
            return new[] { new TimeSegment(StartTime, other.EndTime) };
        }

        // 8-12 Subtract 9-11 = 8-9, 11-12
        // Complete case: two TimeSegments returned
        return new[] { new TimeSegment(StartTime, other.StartTime), new TimeSegment(other.EndTime, EndTime) };
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", StartTime, EndTime);
    }
}
```

And then:

```
var schedules = new List<TimeSegment> { new TimeSegment(new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 08, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 16, 00, 00)) };

var bookings = new List<TimeSegment> 
{
    new TimeSegment(new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 09, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 10, 00, 00)),
    new TimeSegment(new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 12, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 14, 00, 00)),
    new TimeSegment(new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 13, 00, 00), new DateTime(2017, 03, 14, 15, 00, 00)),
};

foreach (TimeSegment booking in bookings)
{
    var schedulesNew = new List<TimeSegment>();

    foreach (TimeSegment schedule in schedules)
    {
        var diff = schedule.Subtract(booking);
        schedulesNew.AddRange(diff);
    }

    schedules = schedulesNew;
}
```

There "core" of this is a `Subtract` function that given a `TimeSegment` subtracts from this another `TimeSegment`, returning 0, 1 or 2 `TimeSegment`s... Then iteratively we subtract all the bookings from the `TimeSegment`s that we produced from the previous booking.

Comment: I had to do something similar to this (it was a bit more complicated though), and ended with a recursive function and a hell to mantain code. This code seems a lot more cleaner and clearer. +1